# Solving Poisson equation with arbitrarily shaped Dirichlet boundary

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, poissons-equation

I have a software that can solve 2D Poisson equation with **rectangular** Dirichlet boundaries. It is amazingly fast and I really need to use it. However, the equation that I want to solve is defined on arbitrary boundaries (not rectangular). Is there way to solve such a problem by redefining it on a rectangular domain? Approximate solution is also accepted.

Comment: It is sometimes possible to find a transformation that maps the domain of interest to, say, the unit square (or some other rectangular domain). This would however turn your problem into a variable coefficient Poisson equation, as the transform would introduce Jacobians in the equation. If your solver can handle variable coefficients, you might be in good shape.

Comment: @ekkilop Thanks for the help. Do you know any good reference book for variable coefficient Poisson equation?

Comment: Book, no; but the literature on the subject is extensive (or so a google search suggests). Darcy's law in oil reservoir models boils down to a variable coefficient Poisson problem, so perhaps there is some help to be found.

Comment: Are you able to edit your software? I am sure it uses something like the FFT, multigrid, finite element, or one of the other optimized methods for solving Poisson on a rectangle.  If you're able to edit your method, or code one yourself, well then it may be possible.  If not, then mapping the problem onto a rectangle may be the best you can do, though not recommended.

Comment: @Merkh I think the software is using FFT and that is why it's fast but as far as I know we cannot use FFT for arbitrary boundaries as it requires periodic  domain. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yeah thats correct. I was just thinking that if you *could* edit it, than it *may* be possible.  For example, it if used finite element method, then you could likely adapt it for your purpose.